# Cannot deploy code to Dynamics CRM instance via Visual Studio

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

**Project Background**

My project runs on Dynamics CRM & we have developed many plugins for it with the Visual Studio 2012.

---

I usually connects to CRM as follows

1. Open Visual Studio CRM Solution
2. Navigate to Tools -> Connect to Dynamics CRM Server
3. Specify CRM Discovery Service Name
4. select HTTPS
5. Click Connect
6. Check Use Default Credentials
7. Click Log on
8. Select the Organization (Production or Sandbox instance)
9. select the solution in the organization

Then when deploying Solutions

1. Right click the Solution
2. clean it
3. build it
4. deploy it

---

**Problem**

But recently it is not possible to connect to the CRM SANDBOX. I'm sure there is no wrong in the process since I have done it many times previously.

it appears as follows

1. Open Visual Studio CRM Solution
2. Tools -> Connect to Dynamics CRM
3. Enter CRM Discovery Service Name
4. choose HTTPS & Click Connect
5. Log in using Credentials
6. SELECT THE ORGANIZATION AS SANDBOX(DEV)

> **Dialog box gets Closed, but no error. Some time Visual studio gets restarted. So no way to deploy solutions to the sandbox.**

[image: Image of Connect to Dynamic Server Dialog box]

**Things I Tried so far**

- run VS as Administrator
- Add the `Global Section` to solution file (.sln) using text editor.
- Replaced the `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll` in CRM Developer Tools add-on
- Added following lines to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config`

  ```
  <dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="6.0.0.0-6.1.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  ```
- Tried to connect by installing 3rd party tools such as CRM Toolkit from Visual studio package manager

Any support is welcome.

Comment: Can you login to the GUI of this Org? Did you check the Security Roles of your CRM user? Are you facing this issue with an CRM Online instance (as your screenshot suggests) or is this an On Premise instance?

Comment: Hi @Filburt, yes actually I can log into the same instance from `org_name.crm5.dynamics.com` & I have double checked about the privilages & user account I'm trying to login has Admin rights.
this is a Online instance.
Problem is completely strange

Comment: Your screenshot shows disco.crm4.dynamics.com - or is that "crm5" a typo in your comment?

Comment: Have you tried to update your CRM SDK version. I also had the same problem with my dev environment & problem got solved after I updated to the Microsoft Dynamics 365.

Comment: @Filburt Sorry there is a Typo in my previous comment. It should be crm4

Comment: @OmalPerera I ll update the dev environment &  try your solution.

Comment: I am not sure if it's smart to let people know the exact length of your passphrase… you might want to contact SO staff to clean that up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also got the same exact problem before couple of months. And this is the worked Solution for me.

> **Solution**

1. Updated the Visual Studio for **VS2015** (In my case Microsoft Dynamics 365 SDK didn't support for Visual studio 2013)
2. Uninstall the current Microsoft Dynamics CRM Toolkit (mine was 2013)
3. Install the **Microsoft Dynamics 365 SDK** (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=50032)

   - Contains the complete SDK for

     - Microsoft Dynamics 365
     - *Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online* (related to your instance)
     - Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 (on-premises)
4. Install **Microsoft Dynamics 365 Developer Toolkit** (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DynamicsCRMPG.MicrosoftDynamicsCRMDeveloperToolkit)

   - Go to `Tools` menu -> click `Extension Manager`
   - In `Extension Manager`, in the left pane, click `Online Gallery`
5. After a restart your computer, run the project.

   - There can be some errors while loading the project, Since we have update the Visual Studio for a upper version. You might need to migrate your project & resolve error messages.
6. Try to get connect with CRM instance using CRM Explorer.

   - Interface should be different than previous one, As follows
     [image]

**NOTE** - Please confirm that you have right privileges to connect to the instance as the first step.

Comment: I Can't believe it.. finally I was able to connect to the CRM server. Still I do have some build errors due to project migration from VS 2012 to VS 2015. But my problem solved.